# How do I give a function to only the second frame of a movie-clip? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, function, navigation, movieclip

I want to create a function that only allows the second frame of a movie clip to allow navigation of SWF. The "2button" is the original movie-clip while the "unlock2" is a different movie-clip on the second frame of "2button"

I tried:

```
//test
    public function open(){
        2button.unlock2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickjump2);
        function clickjump2(event:MouseEvent) {
            gotoAndStop("play2");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions or improvements to this would be greatly appreciated :D!

Comment: Don't name instances starting with a digit, due to common identifier parsing policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function open():void
{
    2button.unlock2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickjump2);
}

function clickjump2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //check if 2button is at frame 2
    if (2button.currentframe==2)
    {
        gotoAndStop("play2");
    }
}
```

ps: as Versper pointed out, dont start names with numbers